# Is it possible to add several complicated conditions in twitterStream.filiter?

Tags: python, twitter, streaming

This code is crawling tweets which contains some keyword, and writing coordinates of the tweets on a newly created csv file.
Is it possible to add multiple conditions such as the below by modifying "twitterStream.filter(track=["food”])"?

```
keywords = ‘food'
limit = 1000
near = 'Detroit MI'
within = '15km'
since = '2018-06-01'
until = '2018-06-05'
lang = ‘en'
```

I know filterquery can contain multiple conditions, but I’m not sure It can also include complicated conditions such as place, start date or end date. Also I wonder whether filterquery can be used on python.
Besides this code creates csv file nothing but empty file even though when it is running it prints the coordinates of tweets well.

here is the full code below.

---

```
import json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

consumer_key=".."
consumer_secret=".."
access_token=".."
access_secret=".."


file = open("result.csv", "w")
file.write("X,Y\n")

data_list = []
count = 0

class listener(StreamListener):

   def on_data(self, data):
       global count

       #How many tweets you want to find, could change to time based
       if count <= 2000:
           json_data = json.loads(data)

           coords = json_data["coordinates"]
           if coords is not None:
              print(coords["coordinates"])
              lon = coords["coordinates"][0]
              lat = coords["coordinates"][1]

              data_list.append(json_data)

              file.write(str(lon) + ",")
              file.write(str(lat) + "\n")

              count += 1
           return True
       else:
           file.close()
           return False

   def on_error(self, status):
       print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["food"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter only allows a few parameters to be added in the filter:

- delimited
- stall_warnings
- filter_level
- language
- follow
- track
- locations
- count with (deprecated)
- replies (deprecated)
- stringify_friend_id   (deprecated)

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters